# Update column with value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables:
Table1

```
id name node
============
1 John 2277415921,2277415917,2277415929,2277415937
2 Jane 1098140458,1098146293,1098145477,1098140669
```

and Table2

```
id nodeid      name
==================
1  2277415937  Kirk
2  1098140669  Serena
```

I need to `UPDATE` the `name` column in `table1` from `table2` when the value from the `nodeid` column in `table2` is in the `node` column in `table1`

I try it this way, but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.node LIKE '%'+t2.nodeid+'%'
SET t1.name = t2.name
```

Can you please tell me how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a horrible data model.  And in MySQL, `+` only means addition.  You can  use `find_in_set()`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 INNER JOIN 
       table2 t2
       ON find_in_set(t2.node_id, t1.node)
    SET t1.name = t2.name;
```

Note you should spend your efforts fixing `table1` (one row per node rather than in a string).  Don't spend your time trying to make sense of the data model.